# Can't build model with DenseFeature input layer, get "'DenseFeatures' object has no attribute 'shape'"

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, keras-layer

I'm trying to build a Keras model using a DenseFeatures layer as the input; the input comes as a dict of Tensors. TF is insisting that I use model.build() to build the model before optimization, but I can't build it due to DenseFeatures not having an input shape. I get the error

`AttributeError: 'DenseFeatures' object has no attribute 'shape'`

How can I resolve this? Here's my code:

```
    input_layer = tf.keras.layers.DenseFeatures(params.columns)
    predictions = Dense(1, input_dim=len(params.columns), activation='softmax')(input_layer)
    model = Sequential([input_layer, predictions])
    model.build()
```

ETA: some further information for insight: I'm not actually fitting the model with this code; rather, I'm creating an EstimatorSpec to use with a Sagemaker model (thus it seems like this will probably require a bit of weird footwork between two different paradigms.)

Comment: You shouldn't need to use build to train the model, should just work with compile & fit from my understanding. However, if you do want to use build you have to give it the input shape (I think something like (None, n_features) should work), see the source code for the build function https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.1.0/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/network.py#L597

Comment: There is a lot wrong in this code, you are mixing the style of the Functional and Sequential APIs, you should decide to one and stick to it, I recommend the Functional API in this case.

Comment: As per my recent edit, I'm not actually training the model; I'm building an EstimatorSpec, and creating the train op seems to require building the model here. And yes, I can fix the code to exclusively use the Functional API, but this does nothing to address the problem I'm facing here.

Comment: Also, to address Hiho's suggestion: I'm not sure how to properly format the input shape for a DenseFeatures input layer - from other examples it seems like a dict of featurename -> shape should do it, but that gives me errors right now as well.